# Checking if permission is available for GPS_PROVIDER

Tags: android, permissions, location

When location is defined, I get the red underline and it reads: "Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available(with 'checkPermission') or handle a potential 'SecurityException'

How to I fix this?

```
public class map extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private FloatingActionButton plus;
LocationManager lm;
Location location;
double latitude, longitude;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (location==null){
        //Location wasnt gathered
    }else{
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }



    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    plus = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.newPlace);

    plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(map.this, newPlacePop.class));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added the appropriate permission to your AndroidManifest? ie:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Also you could wrap your call in a

```
LocationManager enabledManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
if (enabledManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
    location = enabledManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (location==null){
         //Location wasnt gathered
    }else{
         latitude = location.getLatitude();
         longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
}
```

If you do both of these you should be fine.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add one of the following permissions as a child of the  in your Android manifest. The permit common location:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myapp" >
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
...
</manifest>
```

or

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myapp" >
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
...
</manifest>
```

I recommend reading initial documentation

[location google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location#agregar_los_permisos_al_manifiesto_de_la_aplicacion)

Comment: this is also interest for you  [link](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/location/index.html#location)